# Windows application compatible with Microsft Edge share command

Tags: winforms, microsoft-edge, windows-10-universal

Microsft Edge has a share command that sends a link to the current page to other apps like Mail, OneNote, Skype, etc.

I'd like to obtain that my application appears in that list and can receive the target link.
How can I get this functionality in my Windows Form application in C#? Or I need to convert it in a Windows Universal App? In both case what functionality have I to use?

Thanks,
Danilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge it is not possible to receive shared data to WinForm application from other app.

You can do that it in you UWP app. You need to make change in you package manifest file for adding support and some other configurations.

It is very long to put all the code here so I am giving you some of the links where you can find all the steps to fulfill you requirement. Its a concept not a small code block.

1. Receive data to you app from another apps. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/receive-data).
2. Share data to other apps from you app. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/share-data).
3. Other article with more details. Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_sharing_contract.htm).